# Restrict access to directories through ip address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, apache2.2

I have a webserver with apache, say ip is `12.345.678.90`. In my www directory there are a few sites, say, `site1` and `site2`. Both belong to the same ip address - I created virtual hosts.   Websites are on cakephp framework and there are a lots of directories, for example, `app`, `app/tmp`, `lib`, `lib/Cake` etc. When accessing the website like `http://site1.com` or  `http://site2.com` everything is all right, and no way these directories can be viewed or accessed, but through ip I can see everything.

```
http://12.345.678.90/
http://12.345.678.90/site1/lib
http://12.345.678.90/site1/app
http://12.345.678.90/site1/app/tmp
```

etc - all this directories with containing files for each site are visible. So, how I can prevent any kind of access through ip address ? Actually when opening just the ip `http://12.345.678.90` it just shows nothing, as I had created empty `index.html` file, but I cant do that for all the folders,(or create htaccess for each directory). Can this be handled through single htaccess, or maybe better, by apache config, or by some other way ?

Thanks

Comment: create an htaccess in all dir with deny

Comment: @RakeshSharma, there r hundreds of directories

Comment: @Davo Please try out my answer and see if it is working for you. Thanks

Comment: @chmzzy, I added a comment, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**To disable Directory Listing**

In your Apache configuration file (httpd.conf) file locate the directory section eg: `/var/www/html`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny 
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Remove the word `Indexes` or change `Indexes` to `-Indexes`

Then restart your Apache server `service httpd restart`

**To Restrict Access: Directory Level**

You can restrict access to certain directories by adding the following

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/site1/mydirectory">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</Directory>
```

By adding the above configuration to apache conf file the `mydirectory` will be blocked/restricted from access.

**To Restrict Access: File Level**

If you want to restrict a certain file in a directory. Add -

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/site1/mydirectory">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
    <Files myfile.php>
        Order allow,deny
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

**To prevent access of all files by IP Address**

```
 <Files ~ ".+">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was checking if it works, actually it looks like it is almost done, now trying to access directories it shows 403 forbidden, that is ok, but files are still accessible, for example if I know the exact path of some file I can see the content, e.g. `http://12.345.678.90/site1/app/tmp/error.log` thanks

Comment: but see, I have hundred of directories, and in many of them there r files, I cant create a rule for each `myfile.php` individual file ? Thanks

Comment: @Davo Then restrict access from directory level as shown in the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry man i got busy and could not check this out: it is like this, I can not restrict access for each individual file, because I have diff files in diff directories, but if I restrict access to directories it works only for directories (so I can not access `12.345.67.89/path/to/some/folder`), which means if I know the exact path of some file I can see its content, for  example I can open file `12.345.67.89/files/logs/error.log`. Thanks

Comment: I just found the solution, I edited your answer, if it looks good, pls accept the edit and we I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Davo I'm unable to accept your edit. Therefore I have added you edit my myself.

Comment: no prob, thanks for your effort to help and sry for my latency, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should work(add it to you main .htaccess file)

```
Options All -Indexes
```

this wont't allow other to see the files in your folder